# Proof rank($A$) = rank of adjoint of A

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that the rank of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is equal to the rank of its adjoint? My book mentions this fact and does not proceed to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean adjoint or transpose? (your title says one thing and your question another)

Comment: I'm only aware of the definition of an [adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of a **square** matrix, but you ask about $m\times n$ matrices - indicating that it is not necessarily square. Feel free to educate me about your definition of an adjoint. I suspect it has something to do with exterior algebra. I also suspect that this may have contributed to the mishap in editing your question. Simply a fellow user trying to make sense out of your question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Wrong article, see this one: [Conjugate transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: dimension of the column space is equal to the dimension of the row space.

Comment: Looking for adjoint, not transpose

Comment: the matrix associated to the adjoint of an operator is the transpose of the matrix associated to the operator, @WilliamHo. Unless you're talking about the adjugate matrix, which sometimes is also called adjoint.

Comment: Yes, i believe thats what the question is asking for

Comment: @WilliamHo Yes what? If you expect succinct answers you should post succinct questions, with definitions and your own work so there's no room for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can show this using row and column reduction, or with the following fact: The rank of $M$ equals the largest $k$ for which there is a nonzero $k\times k$ minor.

Comment: Looking for adjoint, not transpose

Comment: @WilliamHo The conjugate transpose, or the adjugate?  In the former case it's trivially equivalent (rank is clearly preserved by conjugate), and in the latter case it's false.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the adjoint = adjugate (as opposed to the transpose, which actually fits operator theory better), then the claim is false.

Consider
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right),
$$
a matrix of rank two. Its adjugate/adjoint is
$$
C=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),
$$
a matrix of rank one.

So either the question really is about the transpose (and you owe an apology to certain people), or your question was non-sensical to the extent of asking somebody to prove a false claim. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Rank of Matrix A is the number of leading 1's that it consists  when it is in reduced row echelon form. Therefore, the number of leading 1's a Matrix A is the same when it is Transposed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Looking for adjoint, not transpose